# Python socket server not printing the received data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sending a string from a python client to a python socket server

here is the server side code where i am printing the received value :

```
def threaded_client(connection):
    while True:
        data        = connection.recv(2048)
        print(data)
        datatemp    = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(datatemp)
        message     = datatemp.split('_')
        print(message[0])
while True:
    Client, address = ServerSocket.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, ))
ServerSocket.close()
```

and on the server side i am printing `print(data)` , `print(datatemp)` and `lit('_')` but non of these print statements is printing anything

What am i doing wrong ?

**UPDATE 1:**

I am using these Imports:

```
import socket
import os
from _thread import *
```

Here is the full server code :

```
import socket
import os
from _thread import *

ServerSocket = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 34534
ThreadCount = 0
try:
    ServerSocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print('Waitiing for a Connection..')
ServerSocket.listen(5)

def threaded_client(connection):
    while True:
        data        = connection.recv(2048)
        print(data)
        datatemp    = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(datatemp)
        message     = datatemp.split('_')
        print(message[0])
while True:
    Client, address = ServerSocket.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, ))
ServerSocket.close()
```

Comment: So what output *do* you get from this server code?

Comment: `Waitiing for a Connection..
Connected to: 127.0.0.1:18539`    <===========only this

Comment: You seem to be using `start_new_thread`. I was under the impression that this was python2 only. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: i am using Python 3.8

Comment: Ok, please update your question with the imports you are using.

Comment: @quamrana updated the OP just now

Comment: Well, it works for me. I just had to add: `if not data: break` so that when the client closes their connection, the while loop exits.